# Heroku: was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest - request has been blocked

Tags: api, http, heroku, https

UPDATE:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#/employees'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint
>   'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=design1online'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I'm trying to call the below api from one of my app in heroku and I'm getting the below error

Do I need to add-on SSL?

I have even tried without `http:` something like this:
`//api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=design1online`

API call:
`http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=design1online`

Error:

> failed to load resource: net::err_ssl_protocol_error

Comment: Any luck?  Same thing over here :(

Comment: No luck... I haven't tried after this error.. if you find any solution please feel free to post here...

Comment: Getting this on heroku/cloudflare setup with stripe callback.

Comment: replace the url by `https://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=design1online` but you might get this error net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score -1):

adding S to the http tag actually worked for me, I just had the issue today
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?region=GB"></script>`